# Почему неправильно отображается QScrollArea?(PyQt5, Python3)

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlayout, qgridlayout

У меня есть код, который я оставлю ниже.

Класс `Label` принимает путь к изображению и закругляет его края. Из-за некоторых обстоятельств буду использовать его экземпляры вместо кнопок.

В классе `MyWindow` я создаю два QGridLayout'а - `box1` и `box3` и один QVBoxLayout - `box2`:

1. В `box2` добавляю кнопку `button`.
2. Создаю QScrollArea(`scrollArea`) и привязываю ее к `box3`
3. `box3` наполняю двумя виджетами QLabel, которые получаю из класса
   `Label`.
4. `box2` и `scrollArea` помещаю в box1.

Все это может показаться лишними, но мне действительно нужно такое количество контейнеров. Этого не будет видно в оставленном мною коде, т.к. перед созданием вопроса я пытаюсь упростить ситуацию, чтобы было проще искать ошибки.

Сейчас у меня есть минимум две проблемы.

**Первая проблема:**

Почему-то QScrollArea отказывается принимать нормальные размеры. Даже если растянусь окно на весь экран, элементы `box3`(а их всего два) не будут видны полностью. Полосы прокрутки остаются на своих местах, хотя виджетам хватило бы места.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если добавить третий QLabel:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вторая проблема:**
Я пытаюсь применить метод `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)` к `scrollArea`. Но, почему-то это работает совсем не так, как мне хотелось - пропадают обе полосы прокрутки(горизонтальная и вертикальная). Я не знаю, в чем дело.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне починить код?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button') 
        self.button.setFixedSize(60, 60)

        self.label1 = Label('picture1.png')
        self.label1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.label2 = Label('picture1.png')

        self.new_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New Button')

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()                                         # QVBoxLayout       
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff) #<--- ПРИВОДИТ К НЕПРАВИЛЬНОМУ ОТОБРАЖЕНИЮ
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.box3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget)                           # QGridLayout
        self.box3.setSpacing(200)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label2, 0, 1) 

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                                     # QGridLayout
        self.box1.addWidget(scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1)

    def click(self):
        for row in range(self.box3.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.box3.columnCount()):
                w = self.box3.itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
                w.deleteLater()
        self.box3.addWidget(self.new_button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPD: Я хочу, чтобы  контейнер QGridLayout в QScrollArea занимал все свободное пространство окна, которое не занимает вертикальный контейнер `box2`. Еще на картинке виджеты контейнера `box3` перескакивают на другую строчку, если им не хватает места. Понимаю, что наглею, но, если это будет не трудно, расскажите, как можно добиться такого?
Чтобы было понятнее нарисовал схему:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все работает как написано. Замените `self.box3.setSpacing(200)` на `self.box3.setSpacing(20) `. Вы видимо сделали опечатку ?

Comment: Я так сделал из-за того, что эта область должна быть очень большой, я хотел растянуть ее вообще на всю область, которую не занимает вертикальный контейнер. Если сделать 20 и добавить третий QLabel произойдет то же самое:(

Comment: Немного обновил вопрос и написал конкретнее

Comment: Могу нарисовать подробную схему того, что хочу

Comment: да, нарисуйте, что вы хотите получить и объясните лучше  т.к. задача QScrollArea состоит в создании виджета, 
который может иметь большой размер в области просмотра.

Comment: Нет проблем! Я напишу здесь комментарий, когда все будет готово

Comment: @S.Nick, прошу прощения, что так долго. Я пытался сделать все аккуратнее и понятнее. Сейчас все готово

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы хотите сделать - `Резиновая лента`.

для этого нам нужен - `class ListWidget(QListWidget):`.

также посмотрите в `class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):` где задействована `self.listWidget`

Нажимайте на кнопку `Button`, изменяйте размер окна.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        self.resize(520, 400)
        # Скрыть горизонтальную полосу прокрутки
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        # Невозможно отредактировать
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.IgnoreAction)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.ContiguousSelection)
        # Установите слева направо, оберните и упорядочьте по порядку
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        # Интервал позиций
        self.setSpacing(10)
        # Резиновая лента (для эффекта выбора рамки)
        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QSize(140, 140))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(140, 140)
        self.setMinimumSize(140, 140)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)    

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(140, 140, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', clicked=self.onButton) 
        self.button.setFixedSize(60, 60)

        self.listWidget = ListWidget()                                         # +++

        self.label1 = Label('head3.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label1)                                  # +++ ...
        self.label1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.label2 = Label('Ok.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label2)
        self.label3 = Label('head3.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(self.label3)

        self.new_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('New Button')

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()                                                
        self.box2.addWidget(self.button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)                                     
        self.box1.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0)                            # +++ 
        self.box1.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.box1.addLayout(self.box2, 0, 1) 

    def click(self):
        self.listWidget.hide()
        self.box1.addWidget(self.new_button, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.new_button.show()

    def onButton(self):
        self.new_button.hide()
        self.listWidget.show()
        label = Label('im.png')
        self.listWidget.makeItem(label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Резиновая лента')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я очень вам благодарен!

Comment: @MAXIM045 изучайте, будет чем завтра заниматься :)

Comment: разбираю код, почему-то не могу найти в гугле предназначения `_rubberPos` и `_rubberBand`. Соответственно, не понимаю, как настраивать эту рамку(мне бы хотелось ее вообще удалить). Можно ли где-то почитать об этом?

Comment: Вы не знаете какой-нибудь замены QListWidget? Я понимаю, что наглею, но мне больше не у кого просить помощи.

Comment: @MAXIM045 я посмотрю ваши вопросы чуть позже.

Comment: Спасибо. Не обижайтесь на меня, пожалуйста